# Rudimentary program TypeError. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python

What am I doing wrong in this simple program? Thanks in advance.

```
>>> x=input("x: ")   
x: 2    
>>> y=input("y: ")    
y: 4   
>>> print (y*x)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    print (y*x)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
>>>
```

Comment: You can't multiply `str`s, which is what `input()` gives you. For example, what is `"tom" * "apple"`?

Answer (score 1):

x,y are strings. You need to do int(x). You might want to catch the exception if either of those is not an integer (empty (user only pressed return), whitespace, symbols, letters).

```
print (int(y) * int(x))
```

[This must be a duplicate of other questions here...]

Answer (score 0):

You have probably entered `input` as `"4"`.Only then it is of type `str`.If you enter just `4` for input then t will be `int`.Then your program will run fine.If you give it as `string` then use

```
print (int(x)*int(y))
```

Use `type(x)` to see the type.

Answer (score -2):

the input() method returns a string value. To get a numerical value, use eval()

```
x = eval(input("x: "))
```

Comment: `eval()` rather than `int()` is a security hole, you could have a script injection attack. Just use `int()`.

Comment: True, though I doubt anyone struggling with this sort of concept is going to be developing in an environment where that would be an issue :P

Comment: @Alecg_o: also, it's massive overkill. There are 20 reasons against using it and 0 for.